# Why can't i use same file channel twice in TCL

Tags: tcl, user-input

I was writing a TCL program which looked something like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set fInp [open file1.txt r]
while {[gets $fInp line] >= 0} {
      statement 1
      statement 2
}

statement 3
statement 4

while {[gets $fInp line] >=0} {
      statement 5
      statement 6
}

close $fInp
```

I was expecting this to work fine , but to my surprise , the second while loop was not getting executed at all.
I came to a conclusion that we cannot read a file in TCL twice using same file descriptor (or channel)

So I closed the fInp and opened that file again using fInp2 , and it worked !

What is the reason behind this behavior , and is there any other way of doing it ?

Thanks

Comment: Why'd you delete your question about reading a word at a time? I had an answer ready to submit.

Comment: Sorry Shawn. I did it because i figured it out myself using 'gets' command , all I had to do was to use proper logic. You would have also used gets command as well, right?

Comment: Deep down inside a command that reads a word each time it's called the way `gets` reads a line each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal behavior for reading from files in every programming language and OS I'm familiar with. Once you read to the end of the file in the first loop, there's nothing left to read. You can reset and adjust the internal offset into the file's contents using the [`seek`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/seek.html) command, though.

```
seek $fInp 0 start
```

after the first loop will reset it to the beginning of the file so you can read it again in the second loop.

Comment: The `start` is optional; that's the default value for that parameter.

Comment: @DonalFellows Yeah, but I like to be explicit. Or maybe I've used `lseek()` too much in C.